# Правильно ли расставлены запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Работа с обращениями надзорных организаций (прокуратура, ГЖИ), и депутатов Государственной думы Российской Федерации.

Answer (score 4):

Работа с обращениями (кого?) надзорных организаций (прокуратура, ГЖИ) и депутатов Государственной думы Российской Федерации.

Запятая не нужна, однородные дополнения связаны одиночным союзом И. Вставка на постановку знаков препинания не влияет.